# How to add a class to the current clicked element but not the others in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to add a class to only the div that I click on and not the other siblings, so one div is showing at any time.

**HTML**

```
<div class="c-card">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child">Child 3</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".js-sidebar-video-link-single-in-conversation").on("click", function(){
 $(".child").each(function() {
                                  
 let videoID = $(this).data("video-id");
 let cvid2 = $(this).data("video-number");

 if (videoID === cid && cvid === cvid2) {
   $(this).addClass("is-visible");                      
 }

 if ($(this).hasClass(".show")) {
  $(".in-conversation .is-visible").siblings().hide();             
 } 
 });
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting a `click` event?  When/where does your code run?

Comment: yes I am using a click event. See the edited code

Comment: Which div are you expecting the click event on? The selector that you're binding the click event to is nowhere in the code you've shared.

Comment: `.js-sidebar-video-link-single-in-conversation` isn't in your code.   Regardless, you just need to keep a copy of `this` for the item clicked `var clicked=this;` then you can use it inside the each - if you really need an `each`.   What's `cid`?   Please try to add enough detail, see [mcve]

Comment: Are you clicking a "card" to then show a related div?  *"so one div is showing at a time"* won't allow you to click on the others if they're hidden...

Comment: Hi all, thank you all for your answers. I managed to figure this one out in the end by using the nextAll to add classes to ones which were not active and was not the current one